# How to destroy a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) and using [bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) to select a range for which data will be shown in Datatables.

It is working fine.

The problem is when I select a new range in daterangepicker, it provides me with a callback function where I can do my stuff.
In that callback function, I'm calling Datatables again. But since the table is already being created, how can I destroy the previous table and show a new one in it's place?

Kindly help. I'm stuck. :(

EDIT:
I've the following code:

```
$(element).daterangepicker({options},
function (startDate, endDate) { //This is the callback function that will get called each time
$('#feedback-datatable').dataTable({
                        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                            "oPaginate": {
                                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                                "sNext": "Next"
                            }
                        },
                        "aoColumnDefs": [{
                            'bSortable': false,
                            'aTargets': [2,4]
                        }],
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "aoColumns": [
                                      {"sWidth": "20%"},
                                      {"sWidth": "15%"},
                                      {"sWidth": "45%"},
                                      {"sWidth": "15%"},
                                      {"sWidth": "5%"}
                                      ]
                    });
}
```

Comment: Show us your code, but you could use `if(oTable != null)oTable.fnDestroy();`

Comment: Added my code into the question. Can you kindly explain how to destroy?

Comment: Why do you need recreate your datatable? You could refresh the existing one : `oTable.fnDraw(false);`

Comment: BTW oTable is your datable instance : `oTable = $('#feedback-datatable').dataTable( {...} );`

Comment: So what is otable? Do I need to do something like var oTable = $('#feedback-datatable').dataTable({...})? Where do I write oTable.fnDraw? Can you kindly guide in answer?

Comment: oTable is the datable instance. Check the API page : http://datatables.net/api there are working JSBin demo for each functions. fnDestroy or fnDraw in your case. Show details => Run in JS Bin

Comment: Ok, In my case I can redraw the table, but since the DOM elements still remain in the HTML, the table doesn't get updated. Is there any way to completely remove the DOM elements too? Or do I have to do it the 'raw' way. jQuery.html("")?

Answer (score 29):

To completely delete and remove the datatable object with its DOM elements you need to :

```
//Delete the datable object first
if(oTable != null)oTable.fnDestroy();
//Remove all the DOM elements
$('#feedback-datatable').empty();
```

Comment: Hmm..I can't empty the whole DOM that's between the <table></table> markup as I'm using AngularJS to populate dynamic values inside that table. So I've placeholders that contain handlebars e.g. <td>{{name}}</td> etc. Is there any way I can delete only the content of the table?

Comment: Since you're using angular I'd suggest that you use the 'serverside processing' functionality of datatables, even if you're not doing anything serverside (http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side)

Comment: Sorry; doesn't work for me, and is ambiguous. My console says fnDestroy is not defined. I also have no "oTable" defined, and neither does the question, so that obviously references something else. What works in regard to this question is $('#feedback-datatable').dataTable().fnDestroy(); or more generally $([table selector]).dataTable().fnDestroy();

Comment: @Josh This code works perfectly. oTable is your datable instance oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {...} ); If oTable is not defined in your case, this code will obviously not work.

Comment: This method works for me. In my case, for large tables (1000s of rows). The destroy method is extremely slow. Any workarounds there?

Comment: @JeffTsui I am not using DataTable for long time now, but you could try to hide the table before destruction.

Answer (score 14):

Just add this parameter to your declaration:

```
"bDestroy" : true,
```

Then whenever you want to "recreate" the table it won't drop an error

P.S. You can create a function to get the required parameters and then reinitialize the table with different options at runtime.

For example I use this one in my programs, if it helps you can adapt it to your needs

```
 initDataTable($('#tbl1'), 2, 'asc', false, false, 25, false, false, false, 'landscape', rptHdr);  /* Initialize Table */
```

```
/*---------------------- Datatable initialization  --------------------------- */
/*
 * @$table           Table id which be initialized
 * @sortCol          Column number that will be initially sortered 
 * @sorOrder         Ascendant (asc) or Descendant (desc)
 * @enFilter         Boolean value to enable or not the filter option
 * @enPaginate       Boolean value to enable or not the filter option
 * @dplyLength       Number of records contained per page when pagination is enabled
 * @enInfo           Boolean value to show or not the records info
 * @autoWidth        Boolean value to enable or not table autowidth
 * @enTblTools       Boolean value to enable or not the table tools addin
 * @pdfOrientation   Page orientation (landscape, portrait) for pdf documents (required enTblTools == enabled)
 * @fileName         Output file naming (required enTblTools == enabled)

  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
function initDataTable($table, sortCol, sortOrder, enFilter, enPaginate, dplyLength, enInfo, autoWidth, enTblTools, pdfOrientation, fileName) {
    
    var dom = (enTblTools) ? 'T' : '';

    var oTable = $table.dataTable({
        "order": [
            [sortCol, sortOrder]
        ],
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "dom": dom,
        "bFilter": enFilter,
        "bSort": true,
        "bSortClasses": true,
        "bPaginate": enPaginate,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": dplyLength,
        "bInfo": enInfo,
        "bAutoWidth": autoWidth,
        "tableTools": {
            "aButtons": [{
                    "sExtends": "copy",
                    "sButtonText": "Copy",
                    "bHeader": true,
                    "bFooter": true,
                    "fnComplete": function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash, sFlash) {
                        $().shownotify('showNotify', {
                            text: 'Table copied to clipboard (no formatting)',
                            sticky: false,
                            position: 'middle-center',
                            type: 'success',
                            closeText: ''
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "Excel (CSV)",
                    "sToolTip": "Save as CSV file (no formatting)",
                    "bHeader": true,
                    "bFooter": true,
                    "sTitle": fileName,
                    "sFileName": fileName + ".csv",
                    "fnComplete": function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash, sFlash) {
                        $().shownotify('showNotify', {
                            text: 'CSV file saved in selected location.',
                            sticky: false,
                            position: 'middle-center',
                            type: 'success',
                            closeText: ''
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sPdfOrientation": pdfOrientation,
                    "bFooter": true,
                    "sTitle": fileName,
                    "sFileName": fileName + ".pdf",
                    "fnComplete": function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash, sFlash) {
                        $().shownotify('showNotify', {
                            text: 'PDF file saved in selected location.',
                            sticky: false,
                            position: 'middle-center',
                            type: 'success',
                            closeText: ''
                        });
                    }
                },
                {
                   "sExtends": "Other",
                   "bShowAll": true,
                   "sMessage": fileName,
                   "sInfo": "Please press escape when done"
                }
            ]
        }
        /*"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );}*/
    });
    /* If is IE then avoid setting the sticky headers */
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) && enPaginate == false) {
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(oTable);
    }

    return oTable
}
```

Ivan.

Comment: Most simple approach and therefore, best approach, IMO.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but since I bumped into a similar issue and resolved it.

The following should do the trick (the comments are coming from the [DataTable API doc](http://legacy.datatables.net/api)).

```
// Quickly and simply clear a table
$('#feedback-datatable').dataTable().fnClearTable();

// Restore the table to it's original state in the DOM by removing all of DataTables enhancements, alterations to the DOM structure of the table and event listeners
$('#feedback-datatable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Comment: After 4 hours of searching that was the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: finally, after wasting a lot of time to `destroy` the table, finally, this is the correct one.

Answer (score 7):

For DataTables 1.10, the calls are:

```
// Destroy dataTable
$('#feedback-datatable').DataTable.destroy();

// Remove DOM elements
$('#feedback-datatable').empty();
```

Answer (score 2):

**For the google searchers**

Very hardly I managed to destroy the `Datatable`, Empty it's all previous data before loading new data and re-initializing Datatable by doing like this,

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#myTbl")) {
      ("#myTbl").DataTable().destroy();
}
$('#myTbl tbody > tr').remove();

...

// Load table with new data and re-initialize Datatable
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer with an example?  How do you rebuild the columns?

Answer (score 1):

On DataTables 1.10 and above you can use `"destroy": true`

Read more details [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

Answer (score 0):

From [DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#tableDestroy').on( 'click', function () {
table.destroy();
});
```

Reload a full table description from the server, including columns:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#submit').on( 'click', function () {
    $.getJSON( 'newTable', null, function ( json ) {
        table.destroy();
        $('#myTable').empty(); // empty in case the columns change

        table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
            columns: json.columns,
            data:    json.rows
        } );
    } );
});
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#feedback-datatable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

this should destroy dataTable, then you will have to reinitialize dataTable.