# How to recreate a table with jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[I'm essentially using the top answer here ( from sdespont) to try to destroy some tables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172873/how-to-destroy-a-datatable)

I have one table that shows me the status of a .csv file being uploaded.

**FileuploadTable:**

```
FileName FileType FileSize AvailableActions
```

I have a second table that is the table displaying data from the .csv file.

I need provide the user the ability to reset the form, i.e. get rid of the .csv, and get rid of all of the data, `destroy()` the two tables separately, and `empty()` them of all the data that was there initially.

Here is the issue I'm running into.

I can't seem to *set* the column titles of FileUploadTable after `destroy()` and  `empty()`. When I attempt to upload a new file, the  elements are still on the page, just empty, though the same initialization is being called

I can't seem to *get rid* of the column titles in CSVTable after `destroy()` and `empty()`. When I attempt to upload a different csv, it tries to match column headers to the ones that *should have been destroyed*, but they don't match because, though CSVTable was destroyed and emptied, the column titles are still there...?

Not sure what I'm missing. They're being set properly on initial create.

```
$(elem).DataTable()
```

Can anyone show me a basic working implementation of destroying/emptying datatables, then re initializing with different data, so I can try to mimic it. My brain is mush from looking at their docs for the last 3 days, making no progress.

Example of my data object

```
[
    {
        //key = column title
        //"val" = data in row
        //object = row
        key: "val",
        //i.e.
        FirstName: "Bob",
        LastName: "Barker",
        Age: 800,
        //etc
    },
    //etc
]
```

Comment: Let us see the code. You are asking for a solution to a programming issue in a specific portion of code, without showing that code ..?

Comment: I would if I could... I don't understand the code, I could post where and how it's being initialized, but how the dom is being generated dynamically is woven into the whole architecture, making spaghetti seem like an understatement. I'm sure I wouldn't get away with posting a few hundred lines of code :C

Comment: and really I'm asking for a basic working implementation of destroying and then re initializing datatables with mock data object

Comment: OK, which format does the data have - is it array based, like `[[item],[item], ..]` or JSON `[{item},{item},...]` ?

Comment: edited OP with an example of object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. You can make a simple iteration over your data using `Object.keys()` that produces a column object on the fly holding corresponding `data` and `title` values :

```
var columns = [], keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
   columns.push({ data: keys[i], title: keys[i] });
}
```

Use that inside a general function that initialises the table and take care of destroying and emptying if already initialized :

```
var table = null;
function initTable(data) {
    var columns = [], keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        columns.push({ data: keys[i], title: keys[i] });
    }                  
    if (table) {
        table.destroy();        
        $('#example').empty(); 
    }        
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
       data: data,
       columns : columns
    })  
}
```

Now imagine the following is the `success` handlers of your AJAX calls, or however you get the new data that should be populated to the table :

```
$('#insert1').on('click', function() {
  var data = [
    { FirstName: "Bob", LastName: "Barker", Age: 800 },
    { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Age: 'N/A' }
  ]    
  initTable(data);
})    
$('#insert2').on('click', function() {
  var data = [
    { Animal : "Lion", Taxon : 'Panthera leo' },
    { Animal : "Cheetah", Taxon : 'Acinonyx jubatus' }
  ]
  initTable(data);
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d5pb3kto/**